# Cannot understand the matchPath in a route configuration that is used with redirectTo

Tags: angular12

I have this route

```
  {path: 'dfdfdf/:param', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch : 'prefix'}
```

If I type "localhost:4200/dfdfdf" on the browser I get an error that any routes were matched

I expected it to redirect to my main page as I specified pathMatch: prefix